# How to choose DAC for ECG simulator

Tags: simulation, dac, ecg

I'm trying to design and build ECG simulator device. It's supposed to output voltage in millivolts range (with microvolts precision) using a pre-configured signal (either pre-recorded heart plot or something like sinusoidal wave or just constant signal). It should have 8 channels (10 wires). ECG uses 1000 probes per second, so simulator probably should provide something like 2000 changes per second. ECG uses 16 bits, so simulator ideally should provide 16 bit precision, but I guess that's not a hard requirement.

I'll use some microcontroller and some DACs. I can deal with microcontroller and digital part, but I'm kind of lost when it comes to DACs and analog electronics.

This is research project and cost is not a significant factor.

1. How do I choose DAC? There are many architectures (r2r, sigma-delta, string, etc). Which characteristics should I look at?
2. Should I choose 8-channel DAC or 2x 4-channel DAC or 8x 1-channel DAC? Does it matter?

AFAIK ECG device uses two channels (hands) with common ground (one leg) for one measurement and 6 channels (breast electrodes around heart) with common ground (another leg) for another measurement. I might be wrong about it, though, this part is kind of tricky to understand for me. What I do know for sure is that ECG devices use 8-channel ADC. One part (2 channels) is converted into 6 plots (I, II, III, aVR, aVL, aVF), another part (6 channels) is output as 6 plots (V1, ..., V6). And those 8 channels are connected by 10 wires to human body (left/right hands, left/right legs, 6 electrodes around heart).

3. How do I downsize voltage? DAC usually produces signal in volts range and I need millivolts. I'm aware of voltage divider scheme. Is is appropriate for 1000x downsizing? I've heard about using operational amplifier in some kind of reverse configuration, should I use it?
4. How do I "shift" voltage? DAC produces something like 0...5V (for example). But I need both positive and negative voltage at different points of time, so I need e.g. -2.5mV ... 2.5mV output. That the part that I don't really understand how to implement.
5. What's the best way to provide a power to this device? As I understand, DAC output depends on quality power input. Should I use battery input? What kind of voltage regulator should I choose? Is it feasible to use batteries to power DACs and something like USB port to power microcontroller?

This is not medical equipment, it's for self-education and research purposes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...so simulator probably should provide something like 2000 changes per second. ECG uses 16 bits, so simulator ideally should provide 16 bit precision, but I guess that's not a hard requirement.

Just to be clear, 2000CPS * 16bits * 8 channels = 256kb/s.  Not a problem for the more powerful micros out there, but the smaller ones will struggle (especially if also doing other tasks such as I2C and USB, etc.)  Factor in some significant overhead when picking the micro to be safe.

> How do I choose DAC? There are many architectures (r2r, sigma-delta, string, etc). Which characteristics should I look at?

Start by investigating each type, then compare them.  Make a table of the differences.  Some are faster, some are more accurate.  Some will allow negative outputs, some won't.  Go to Digikey.com, search for DAC; this will give you a lot of choices for comparison.  Look at the datasheets.  How important is settling time to this application?  Maybe you'll favor power consumption over number of channels... the (optimizing) choices are vast.  R2R is pretty much instantaneous, but takes large amounts of board space and will need op-amp buffered outputs, etc.

> Should I choose 8-channel DAC or 2x 4-channel DAC or 8x 1-channel DAC? Does it matter?

This is a systems-design question, which we can't really answer. It may not matter from a functional standpoint (end goal achieved in any case) but consider all aspects - i.e. is it easier to use one monolithic DAC with marginal specs, or eight R2R DACs and buffers taking up a square foot of board space?  Then there are ancillary questions attached to this, such as can your MCU drive an eight-channel DAC fast enough or jitter-less enough, or can it drive eight independent DACs simultaneously?  How many pins/what speed/overhead would that require?

> How do I downsize voltage? DAC usually produces signal in volts range and I need millivolts. I'm aware of voltage divider scheme. Is is appropriate for 1000x downsizing? I've heard about using operational amplifier in some kind of reverse configuration, should I use it?

A resistor divider *could* be used for 1000x reduction, but keep in mind that anything with resistance introduces some amount of noise ([shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise), [Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) noise.)

Op-amps are not typically used in "reverse", perhaps you mean [negative feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Negative-feedback_applications). But an op-amp would likely be needed, to "buffer" this voltage. A divider from 5V to 5mV would likely use high-value resistors, so as a consequence it will have a high-value impedance, meaning *any* external load on it could skew the result. (Hence, a buffer is needed to reduce this impedance.)

> How do I "shift" voltage? DAC produces something like 0...5V (for example). But I need both positive and negative voltage at different points of time, so I need e.g. -2.5mV ... 2.5mV output. That the part that I don't really understand how to implement.

This would likely be done with an [operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) (opamp.)

To learn how to use op-amps, I suggest Tony Kuphald's [Lessons in Electric Circuits](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/) as a primer.  Specifically, understand DC and AC, then venture into [opamps](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Semi/SEMI_8.html). I also recommend simulating op-amps.  Any sufficiently advanced electronics simulator should be capable of modeling op-amp behavior, at least enough to let you try various configurations and "see" if it really does what you want.  [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) is one such simulator, although it has a learning curve.

You'll need to consider/implement the following:

- A low-noise split supply (such as +5V and -5V) to power the op-amps, so they can reach negative voltages
- Proper biasing, such that 2.5V in = 0V out (or none if using bipolar DAC output)
- A gain (amplification) which is less than 1 (more like .001)
- A low-noise op-amp, which muddles the output as little as possible.

> What's the best way to provide a power to this device? As I understand, DAC output depends on quality power input. Should I use battery input? What kind of voltage regulator should I choose? Is it feasible to use batteries to power DACs and something like USB port to power microcontroller?

I would suggest powering from one source only, such as AC adapter (switch-mode DC output, 7V lets say.) From this, use one [linear regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator) to drop this to 5.00V for the MCU, and another one for the op-amps +5.00V.  Then from the 7V, use a [voltage inverter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/922) to get -7V or so.  From that, use a negative linear regulator to regulate that to -5.00V for the opamps.

You'll want to understand and use [bypass capacitors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bypass+capacitor&t=opera&ia=web) to keep this power clean and glitch-free, along with the big concept of [star ground](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=star+grounding&t=opera&ia=web). Star-grounding simply means to think about where the currents will be flowing in the physical design, and keeping the noisy switched currents (all of the digital stuff) from creeping into the analog stuff (opamps.) Usually this means tying these grounds in one spot (a star) which prevents the noisy digital currents from entering or even being near the analog stuff.

All electronic designs are comprised of building blocks, all built on top of each other.  It may take more than one revision to reach the desired goal; be open to changing something radically or even starting over if needed.  To realize this one:

- Design a prototype PCB.
- Install just the power components.  Ensure the +5 Vdd, +5.00 Vcc, and -5.00 Vee are working properly.  Use an oscilloscope for measurements; sometimes things can oscillate, which is undetectable on a multimeter.
- Install just the DAC(s) and digital stuff.  'Scope the voltages again.  If using USB communications, get that working.  'Scope the DAC outputs.
- Install the analog stuff, 'scope and test.

Note, consider power ground and chassis ground to be completely separate things. Connect the chassis and *one end* of any shielded cables used to Earth ground.

Comment: the DAC might be able to be scaled way down simply by lowering it's reference voltage to an appropriate value, with maybe a precision voltage ref.